# Keras ValueError related to input shape in 1D Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, valueerror

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run a 1D CNN on a 7 band spectral data. The class labels are binary, and I want a single output. I am attaching the code and the outputs. Apparently, it seems that Conv1D is having some problems ingesting the 7 input bands. I have tried looking at the posts that are already out there, but without much success.

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, precision_score, recall_score
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate
from spectral import *
import pysptools.spectro as spectro
import copy
import os
import matplotlib
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd
import shutil


#%% DEFINE THE 1D CNN MODEL ARCHITECTURE
filters=4
kernel_size=4

visible = Input(shape=(7,1))
hidden1 = Conv1D (filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, input_shape=(7,1), activation='relu', name="L1")(visible)
hidden2 = MaxPooling1D()(hidden1)
hidden3 = Dense(2, activation='relu', name="L3")(hidden2)
# hidden4 = Dense(2, activation='relu', name="L4")(hidden3)
output = Dense(1, activation='softmax', name="Output")(hidden3)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)

# Shapes of the input data and label

print("\n7 band spectral data shape:", ern_T_c_d_v.shape) 
print("Class labels shape:", ern_Mask_c_d_v.shape)
            
# Split into test and train
            
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(ern_T_c_d_v, ern_Mask_c_d_v, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
# Note that I have transposed the arrays...

print("\nBefore reshaping")

print("xTrain:", xTrain.shape)
print("yTrain", yTrain.shape)

print("xTest:",xTest.shape)
print("yTest:",yTest.shape)

xTrain = np.reshape(xTrain, (xTrain.shape[0],  1, xTrain.shape[1]))
xTest = np.reshape(xTest, (xTest.shape[0], 1, xTest.shape[1]))

# xTrain=np.expand_dims(xTrain, axis=1)
# xTest=np.expand_dims(xTrain, axis=1)

print("\nReshaped...")
print("xTrain:", xTrain.shape)
print("yTrain:", yTrain.shape)

print("xTest:", xTest.shape)
print("yTest:",yTest.shape)

#%%

# Define the accuracy metrics and parameters
# opt=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

# Run the model
history = model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs=1500)
pd.DataFrame(history.history).plot(figsize=(6,4))
plt.savefig(path+os.sep+'History')
plt.show()
print(history.params)

#%%

# Predict for test data 
yTestPredicted = model.predict(xTest)
```

AND, this is what I get:

```
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectoryCheckOrder:Invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Model: "model_15"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_19 (InputLayer)        [(None, 7, 1)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
L1 (Conv1D)                  (None, 4, 6)              30        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_15 (MaxPooling (None, 2, 6)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
L3 (Dense)                   (None, 2, 4)              28        
_________________________________________________________________
Output (Dense)               (None, 2, 1)              5         
=================================================================
Total params: 63
Trainable params: 63
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None

7 band spectral data shape: (1201, 7)
Class labels shape: (1201,)

Before reshaping
xTrain: (600, 7)
yTrain (600,)
xTest: (601, 7)
yTest: (601,)

Reshaped...
xTrain: (600, 1, 7)
yTrain: (600,)
xTest: (601, 1, 7)
yTest: (601,)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Volumes/256GB/Ceres_Red_FC/NN_Codes/NN_Functional_CNN_1.py", line 181, in <module>
    history = model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs=1500)

  File "/Users/pragya/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

  File "/Users/pragya/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 224, in fit
    distribution_strategy=strategy)

  File "/Users/pragya/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 547, in _process_training_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

  File "/Users/pragya/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 594, in _process_inputs
    steps=steps)

  File "/Users/pragya/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2472, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')

  File "/Users/pragya/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 574, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_19 to have shape (7, 1) but got array with shape (1, 7)
```

I am not able to understand why Conv1D can't accept the 7 input bands. Any ideas how to get around this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try reshaping your input to ```(600, 7,1)```

Comment: @Nachiket I had already given that a try. Didn't work...

Comment: Alright, can you post a minimal reproducible example, with all arrays e.g. ```ern_T_c_d_v``` defined? It would be good if you can reduce the number of dependencies too.

Comment: It looks like you need set `input_shape=(1,7)` instead of `(7, 1)`. I'm not sure what your data is like - but it sounds to me like each band is a feature, or a different column, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change this line

```
xTrain = np.reshape(xTrain, (xTrain.shape[0],  1, xTrain.shape[1]))
xTest = np.reshape(xTest, (xTest.shape[0], 1, xTest.shape[1]))
```

To this

```
xTrain = np.reshape(xTrain, (xTrain.shape[0], xTrain.shape[1], 1))
xTest = np.reshape(xTest, (xTest.shape[0], xTest.shape[1], 1))
```

the fit function works.
To better understand this you need to know that the convolutions have a channel in the shape, you are given a 7 channel example with only one value and you are trying to pass a 4 size kernel to this single input,
They are two ways to solve this you can create an input with 7 values and only 1 channel as the example above or you can do a separable convolution between the channels.

Comment: This worked, but aren't the two codes doing exactly the same thing? Can you please shed some more light on the thing with the channels you mentioned.  Otherwise, please suggest a source where I can know more about this. Thanks a lot...

Comment: You can find a great article [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-basic-introduction-to-separable-convolutions-b99ec3102728) and see the main difference in images, but to put simple your data have the following form `[batch_size, length, channels] ` when you define a kernel in a convolution the kernel need to be smaller that your length and the library creates as many kernels as channels you have

Answer (score 1):

The following is working for me

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate

import numpy as np

nexamples = 200
filters=4
kernel_size=4

xTrain = np.zeros((nexamples,7,1),dtype='float64')
yTrain = np.zeros((nexamples,),dtype='float64')

visible = Input(shape=(7,1))
hidden1 = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, input_shape=(7,1), activation='relu', name="L1")(visible)
hidden2 = MaxPooling1D()(hidden1)
hidden3 = Dense(2, activation='relu', name="L3")(hidden2)
# hidden4 = Dense(2, activation='relu', name="L4")(hidden3)
output = Dense(1, activation='softmax', name="Output")(hidden3)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

# Run the model
history = model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs=1)
```

Comment: I got this error when I ran the above code...```ValueError: A target array with shape (200, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 2, 1) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.```

Comment: I checked again, it works for me. I'm not sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks l lot for the help. I don't understand: the answer by Pedro works, even though it is basically doing the same thing which you have suggested.